# Show added TODOs in PR/Branch in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When I'm working on a PR, I generally keep adding TODOs for things that I want to fix before raising it for review. Now IntelliJ has a way to view TODOs, but it shows all the dozens of TODOs in the project and I have to manually look through them each time.

Is there a way to show TODOs added in a branch (eg, based on the diff from master)?

Failing that, is there a way to show TODOs added by me only?

(I Know intellij has a way to show TODOs only for uncommitted changes, but that's not good enough as I like to commit frequently and fixing all TODOs before every commit isn't doable)